# create setup file for a .netoffice project in advance installer

Tags: office-addins, setup-deployment, word-addins, advanced-installer, netoffice

my project is a addin word with .netoffice.
I tried to create a setup file with advance installer,
The dlls of the debug file are registered,
and I gave administrator access for run setup,

But still my addin is not loaded in Word!

Can anyone help?

Do I have to dll register in another way? Or should I do something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you followed the steps from [Advanced Installer user guide](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-office-addin.html) to package your add-in and this still does not work after installation, then I think the best way to investigate this will be to contact the Advanced Installer support team.